# How to perform inner join in multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframe namely accidents_data which has 15 columns and bad_air_quality_data dataframe whch has 5 columns.

Now i'd like to inner join both data frames on column ['District Name', 'Weekday', 'Hour', 'Month'] and finally keep only the data from accidents_data after joining.

accidents_data:

[image: accidents_data]

bad_air_quality_data:

[image: bad_air_quality_data]

I tried merging both the dataframes using the below line but it does not show any results.

```
accidents_data_bad_air = pd.merge(accidents_data, bad_air_quality_data, on=['District Name', 'Weekday', 'Month', 'Hour'], how='inner')
```

Comment: Looks like you actually want to use the column `Weekday` from your accident df. You could rename `Day` in the air_quality frame to `Weekday` and it should work

Comment: @ChrisA I tried your suggestion. But it gives me the following error
ValueError: You are trying to merge on int64 and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

Answer (score 1):

I think i figured out the solution. While merging the data the datatype of same columns were different.
After making that correction, the merge worked.